# Locating android phone

Tags: samsung, google-account, lost-phone

I lost my phone. I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 with the corresponding newest Android version that's automatically delivered. I never really used the Google Service so it isn't authorized or whatever.

I do have a WhatsApp Web and Telegram Web Version.

Is there any way, also a techy way, of checking where my phone is? It doesn't have to be very precise.

Can I for an instance use the Telegram Web Session to make an HTTP Request from my phone to some homepage and check the IP using the access log and from that the imprecise location? Does anyone have other ideas?

Comment: In addition to Zoe's answer, you might wish to take a look at our [lost-phone tag-wiki](/tags/lost-phone/info) for some alternative possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Without any tracking app (meaning an app that finds the device, for an instance [Google's Find My Device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm) app.

Depending on when and where you lost it, it may not be possible to find it. If it's somehow been turned off (i.e. water damage, it fell from somewhere high, ran out of power, etc) you can't find it.

If you had an app for tracking you would have a chance at using that to find it. Otherwise you're stuck using manual searching.

You could also use other apps as a workaround. If you're using Google Fit and had an internet connection when you lost it, you could probably use that to find where the GPS trail ends. But that assumes it registered activity, it wouldn't be possible to use it if you lost it for an instance at the office or somewhere else that's stationary.

And as far as I know, you can't use Telegram or WhatsApp to ping your phone.

Comment: Getting the IP would be enough since there are actually just 2 places it could be but they are rather big. Tried getting the IP using a telegram bot but ofc, it won't give me the IP of the phone but "of" telegram :P I usually have all tracking disabled. I can't use Google Find My Device since it wants me to verify the device first, for which I need the phone :p but thanks

Comment: So your device isn't associated at all with any gmail account, because if you setup a gmail address it might be a bit easier

Comment: There's a gmail and I did log in sometimes, since I'm using the play store. I just never logged it by web or whatever. As I said, I don't plan on using any such Google Services nor do I ever use my gmail, so I don't really know what verification/authentication methods Google's using. Anyway, I was lucky and found it. I'm gonna set up my own stuff next month to prefent this :)